# How to access an application from the System menu

Tags: menu

I just setup PHPStorm on Ubuntu and it says it can be accessed via the "System Menu" but I can't figure out where that is in Ubuntu 12.10.

I used `gnome-desktop-item-edit` to create a launcher icon.  What is this system menu that is referenced and where can I find it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried pressing `[Super]` (which will open Unity launcher) and typing *PHPStorm*?

If you do, then try to find binary file. There are few commands which, I hope, will help:

```
$ sudo find / -type f -executable -name '*phpstorm*'
```

which will find every file with *phpstorm* phrase in it's name, or

```
$ which phpstorm
```

which will look for binary file in *bin* directories or

```
$ locate phpstorm
```

which will give you similar results to first command, but with non-binary files.

If you'll find binary, then use it's path in launcher creation.